# Android - run a prompt on a schedule

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have a request that an application prompt the user to update (if the policy manager site says an update is available), and if they decline, prompt them again in N minutes.  I have seen similar questions asked but when I tried to implement the code using handlers or timers, the activity is out of scope or a crash happens that I can't quite figure out, the class I am using requires an application context and an activity to get out various string variables and do tasks.

So I would like to generalize the question as maybe I am thinking about it the wrong way:

What is the best way to schedule a prompt for an update that can either be cancelled and return the user to the activity they were on (and then scheduled run again in N minutes), or direct the user to a web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an AlarmManager with a PendingIntent and a BroadcastReceiver.
You set the time with the alarm manager and give it a PendingIntent which you get by using the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` method.
1 of the params you give this method is the BroadcastReceiver class which would receive a call when the time is up where you can do pretty much anything you'd like, which would probably be starting a new activity in your case.

Comment: BroadcastReceiver can't seem to create alert dialogs as they are not an activity.
//after edit: so then I'd have to make another screen just to pop the alert?  i guess at that point I'd just add the buttons to the activity instead of popping an alert.

Comment: If you want the dialog look and feel, you can either create an activity with the Dialog theme or simply do only 1 thing in the activity and that's creating an Alert dialog. By the way, I believe you can save 1 step in my solution by giving the PendingIntent the activity class instead of using the getBroadcast method... I usually prefer working with receivers as it removes the alarm handling from the activity logic.